# Gulp settings javascript object

Tags: javascript, settings, gulp

I am just making some settings for my gulpfile.js but I have a problem.

I have settings - in js literal object - like this:

```
// Directories
 var dirs = {
    source: './src/',
    build: this.source + 'build/'
};

// Files to read.
var paths = {
    sass: {
        src: dirs.source + 'sass/**/*.scss',
        dest: dirs.build + 'css/'
    },
    js: {
        src: dirs.source + 'js/**/*.js',
        dest: dirs.build + 'js'
    }
};
```

but, off course, the `dirs.build` returns `./undefinedbuild/` directory instead of `./src/build/` directory.

Is there any way - or different style of settings - how to fix it (how to make settings in JS)? Literal object notation is best looking for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not object-based, but function-scope based. So this is in your case either `global` or the function you are in. On the other hand, if you type dirs.source directly, this property is not yet defined. Create the literal and then add properties:

```
// Directories
var dirs = {};
dirs.source = './src/';
dirs.build = dirs.source + 'build/'

// Files to read.
var paths = {
    sass: {
        src: dirs.source + 'sass/**/*.scss',
        dest: dirs.build + 'css/'
    },
    js: {
        src: dirs.source + 'js/**/*.js',
        dest: dirs.build + 'js'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
var dirs = {
    source: './src/',
    build: dirs.source + 'build/'
};
```